# Example for highlighting keywords vespa

Tags: vespa

In the documentation of [features](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/features.html), it is said that search engine like keyword highlighting is supported in vespa. I couldn't find any example on how to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You control this in the search definition document on a per field basis

See

- https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/search-definitions-reference.html#bolding
- You can also instruct it do make a dynamic small snippet with the summary:dynamic option

Comment: New link: https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/schema-reference.html#bolding